# How do i make inputs width adapt to table colums width

Tags: php, html, css

I got a php forloop, wich generates a table from a database.
The 2nd row has text inputs for searching.
My problem is, how do i make the inputs width, adapt to the columns?

I made an example in jsfiddle. 
The first table is what i get with inputs.
The second is what i want the inputs to look like.

To make it clear. Table 1 should look like table 2.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EL3PHANTEN/GELZn/)

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td><td>Second Column</td><td>3rd Column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Some database content</td><td>more db content</td><td>more content</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td><td>Second Column</td><td>3rd Column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Some database content</td><td>more db content</td><td>more content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles to te inputs in your CSS:

```
width:  100%;
margin: 0;
border:  0px none;
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c9vG/1/)

**Edit**

The above didn't work in Chrome.  Combining with @Johan Perez answer solves that I think.

CSS:

```
td input {
    width:  100%;
    margin: 0;
    border:  0px none;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[New working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c9vG/2/) (tested in FF, Chrome, IE11)

**Edit 2**
Here is a screen shot from the second fiddle in Chrome:

[image: chrome screenshot]

Can you post how yours looks to see the problem?

Comment: OK.  Had only tested in FF.  Try combining with @Joan Perez answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Safari available to test with.  In what way is it not working there?  Is the border showing, the inout too small, what?

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN: THe second fiddle in my answer looks fine to me in Chrome.  Running latest Chrome (34.0.1847.116 m) on Win 8.1  Did you try the second fiddle ("New working fiddle")?

Comment: In the working fiddle the first table is not looking like the second as i want. Win 7 chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m

Comment: I installed FF, and the tables dont look alike. Maybe i should edit question, to make it clear that table 1 should look like table 2

Comment: If you mean the width of the whole table then you need to set that with CSS too.  I thought the question was about getting the input to take the whole table cell?

Comment: Sorry i might not have been clear enough in my question. I see your screenshot. The inputs all adapt to only Column 1. What i want to achieve is that the table looks like the 2nd table. Where input 1 adapts to its column, and 2 to its etc..

Comment: The inputs adapt to all the columns (that's why no border or space around the inputs is shown in any column).  What you need to do is set the column widths to what you want them to be.  E.g. with a class per column and widths in the CSS

Comment: Okey i got it working now. In the forloop i ad a new class to each of the <td> where there is an input inside. Then i make the same css code for each of the classes. So alot of copy paste in the css file.

Comment: You should be able to apply any CSS that applies to all columns just one.  Either give them a common class, or give the table/row a class and use that as context.  The column-specific classes should only really need to set widths.

Comment: @Adam I tried that allready. On fiddle it works. But in my case it only works if i make a class for each td. They seem to be very similar cases.

Comment: @Adam however the inputs are still to big. The tables dont look exact the same. Like if there is a column named ID. It should be a very small input.

Answer (score 0):

Use width:100% with box-sizing: border-box. An example:

```
<input type="text" width="100%" style="box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;" />
```

Comment: I've just added navigator-specific box-sizing. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
input[type="text"] {
width: 100%;
border: 0px;
outline: 0px;
}
```

[<kbd>Updated Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/GELZn/1/)